# LinearLayout with Fragment inside PopupWindow

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-popupwindow

I am using a PopupWindow to overlay a ViewPager with 5 different Fragments over users IME if he clicks on a specific button. As far as i know at the moment, it is not possible to use a Frgament as content of a PopupWindow. So  my question is: Is it possible to put the Fragment with the ViewPager inside a LinearLayout(for example) and set the LinearLayout as Content of the PopupWindow? And if not, why does it not work if i use the getView() - method of my Fragment to get a view which i can set as content of the PopupWindow

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer for 7 days gave me the possibility to figure it out by myself. As far as I know there is no way to do this, the layout which is the content of the fragment has to be inflated into the popupwindow. I tried it out and it works this way...